# Spark SQL as Service

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

Currently developing an application that extracts data from the plain text files(textbooks) and calculates tf-idf values and store in hive table using spark mllib. I need to search the corpus with keywords to find the book name like a rest service. Is there any REST service available to use spark sql as a service to run a query on it? or Is it possible use Livy to accomplish the above requirement? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible to use livy for this, but if you only want to perform sql queries on hive tables, it would be much simpler to use the spark thrift server.
spark thrift server is a jdbc server that allows you to connect with any jdbc client, and run sql queries.

you can find more info here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#running-the-thrift-jdbcodbc-server
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-thrift-server.html

Comment: thanks a lot for the inputs @lev, actually I am using hive to store tf-idf calculation results. I just  got confused to retrieve the data for further use either from hive directly or load it again on spark and query through spark SQL.